# ¿Cómo pasar datos desde un Adapter a un Fragment?

Tags: android

Para entrar en contexto, tengo un fragment que tiene un RecylerView que lista diferentes usuarios con precio y producto, lo que quiero es sumar los precios y ponerlos en un Textview que se encuentra fuera del RecylerView pero en el mismo Fragment.
Para llenar el Recycler uso un FirestoreRecyclerAdapter, esta es la forma que intento pasarle el dato

```
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ventas_listar,parent,false);

    VentasFragment ventasFragment =  new VentasFragment();
    Bundle bundle =  new Bundle();
    bundle.putDouble("t",total);
    ventasFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

y esta sería la forma en la que intento obtener el dato desde mi Fragment debajo de mandarle el adaptador al Recycler.

```
    if (getArguments()!=null){
        totald= getArguments().getDouble("t");
    }
```

No me funciona este método porque no llega nada,  ayuda con eso porfavor

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizarlo usando mediante una interfaz, crea la interfaz:

```
interface SendData {
    void sendInfo(Double valor);
}
```

En tu Adapter, este serìa una ejemplo, al dar click a tu item mediante un OnClickListener puedes enviar la informaciòn:

```
class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

    List<ExampleItem> items;
    SendData listener;

    ExampleAdapter(List<ExampleItem> items, SendData listener) {
        this.items = items;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Envia informacion a tu Fragment 
                listener.sendInfo(total);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

En tu Fragment implementa la interfaz y recibirias el valor en su mètodo:

```
class YourFragment extends Fragment implements SendData {

    ...
    ...
    ...

    void sendInfo(Double valor) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "El valor recibido es: " + valor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Si el texte view esta fuera de lo que puede controlar el adapter entocnes no podria mandarle a traves del  viewHolder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() :(